# Curiosity about Timber + Unintegrated plugins?

Tags: wordpress, timber

I have a curiosity and beginner question.How do you deal with some (needed if ever) plugins that are not very much compatible when using Timber? maybe like what I mentioned before, the Buddypress plugins?

Comment: What do you mean by "deal with" - in what sense? Timber is just an additional way to create templates in WordPress (with Twig), it won't get in the way of plugins which don't use Twig.

Comment: I mean for example I want to use it to create theme for buddy press but afaik buddypress uses shortcodes and has it's own set of themes it can only deal with... something like it doesn't have an opening to be bridged by timber... I hope what I meant reaches you... :)